# Get WLC running-config including ALL secrets as plaintext

Tags: cisco, wireless

Our WLC 5508 pair is going EOL.  I need to migrate the complete configuration (including secrets) to a new pair of CT3504 WLCs.

The problem I have is when I run `show run-config commands`, username / password secrets are obfuscated with `****`.

I need those secrets as plaintext so I can paste the full configuration into the new WLC pair without loosing any configruation items.  For instance, the mgmtuser entries are all obfuscated:

`mgmtuser add mpenning **** read-write`

I already tried `config switchconfig secret-obfuscation disable` and this still leaves many secrets obfuscated.

How do I get a full WLC configuration including all secrets as plaintext?

Comment: Have you tried "transfer upload"?  You'll probably get hashes, but at least you can copy them.

Comment: @RonTrunk, I have not tried `transfer upload`.  Are you sure that this won't obfuscate secrets?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't have a controller at the moment to test it on.

Comment: Just checked.  They're hashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CLI:**
You can use `transfer upload` (via CLI or GUI).

You should use `transfer upload datatype config` and `transfer encrypt disable` from the CLI to get the WLC's text configuration.

**GUI:**
[image: WLC Transfer upload screen]

In both cases, the passwords are hashed, but not obfuscated.

Comment: `transfer upload` is completely broken for both FTP and TFTP in my version of aireos... I have spent an hour trying so far

Comment: For future users of this answer: it seems that `transfer upload` is rather finicky about the TFTP server being used.  [tftpd32 v4.64](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html) on Windows 10 works; however, [ptftpd](https://pypi.org/project/ptftpd/) running under python (as root) fails.

Comment: I used SFTP with no problems on 8.3.133.0